# HtmlUnit doesn't load javascript correctly

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

I'm trying to scrap contents of a table from [link](https://www.premierleague.com/match/14252).

It's the "Match Stats" table under "Stats" tab.

However, by examine the source using Chrome, the content is actually missing from the container:

```
<tbody class="matchCentreStatsContainer"></tbody>
```

So I'm assuming the content is handled by JavaScript.

I use the following code to load the page, click on "Stats" tab, and then check the page content.

```
    WebClient wc = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    WebRequest request = new WebRequest(new URL("https://www.premierleague.com/match/14252"));
    wc.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    wc.setJavaScriptTimeout(10000);
    wc.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    HtmlPage page = wc.getPage(request);
    wc.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30000);
    HtmlUnorderedList ul = (HtmlUnorderedList) page.getByXPath("//ul[contains(@class, 'tablist')]").get(0);

    //get the stats tab
    HtmlListItem li = (HtmlListItem) ul.getChildNodes().get(2);
    li.click();
    wc.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
    String pageAsXml = page.asXml();
```

But there's still nothing inside the table in my pageAsXml, anything I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have done a short test with your code.
If you disable the line wc.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false); you will see that there is a js error (only with HtmlUnit and not in the browser). Usually this means some javascript code will not be executed. Please open an HtmlUnit issue for this and we can try to solve this problem. Please have a look at [Submitting JavaScript bugs](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingJSBugs.html).